# CASE statement from Oracle to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, count, case

I have the following query that I needed to port to MySQL from Oracle. It executes without any compilation errors in both, but the result table is different. While in Oracle, I get the individual counts under each of the count columns. But in MySQL, regardless of where the counts are supposed to be, they all land up under a5. Like so:

In Oracle: [image]

But in MySQL: [image]

```
select x1.alert_level, count(x1.a1),  count(x1.a2), count(x1.a3), 
count(x1.a4), count(x1.a5) from 
(select  
table_name.column_name alias, 
case when (now() - column_name) <= 7 then 1 end as a1,  
case when (now() - column_name) between 7 and 30 then 1 end as a2, 
case when (now() - column_name) between 30 and 60 then 1 end as a3,
case when (now() - column_name) between 60 and 90 then 1 end as a4, 
case when (now() - column_name) >= 90 then 1 end as a5 
FROM tables
WHERE filter_conditions)  x1  GROUP BY x1.alias;
```

How can I reconcile the differences to make the MySQL output look like the Oracle output? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Is `condition` a column or a more complicated expression?

Comment: It's a simple condition or expression. No columns involved unless specified :)

Comment: Post that expression then. The issue is probably there.

Comment: I don't think it is, as the query actually produces the output, except that it's aggregating it all in a5, rather than under a1 through a4. Nonetheless, I've edited the question.

Comment: Oracle doe snot have a `NOW()` functions AFAIK. So I guess you translated some function of it to NOW(). You probably converted some column form a datetime datatype to one of the datetime datatypes of MySQL. There lies the problem. `NOW()` returns the current timestamp, and (I think it depends on the datatype of `column_name`) but I wouldn't expect a `90` result from the substraction.

Comment: Are you trying to substract dates or timestamps?

Comment: Nope. That's not the problem. It is `sysdate` in Oracle and I changed it for MySQL. The syntax is correct, just that the evaluations are not.

Comment: And yes, I'm trying to subtract timestamps.

Comment: Try `DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, column_name)`

Comment: I tried that. Still no luck. Like I said, I think the issue is not with the condition itself, but with the alias for each case statement.

Comment: Please post a few rows with data for `column_name` and tell us what its datatype is.

Comment: `column_name` is a typical `timestamp` with the date and time in `HH:MM:SS` format.

Comment: Could you provide same samples for "select column_name, now() - column_name from tables" in both databases? Did you tried an explicit cast?

Comment: `datediff` worked perfectly. Thanks ypercube. You might wanna put it as an answer so I can mark it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `datediff` and it worked perfectly!